# Google App Engine Flex environment: ETag HTTP header removed when resource is gzip'd?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have a custom Node.js application deployed on Google App Engine flexible environment that uses dynamically calculated digest hashes to set ETag HTTP response headers for specific resources. This works fine on an AWS EC2 instance. But, not on Google App Engine flexible environment; in some cases Google App Engine appears to removes my application's custom ETag HTTP response header and this severely degrades the performance of the application. And, will be needlessly expensive.

Specifically, it appears that Google App Engine flex environment strips my application's ETag header when it gzip's eligible resources.

For example, if I use curl to request a utf8::application/json resource AND do not indicate that I will accept the response in compressed format then everything works as I would expect --- the resource is returned along with my custom ETag header that is a digest hash of the resource's data.

curl https://viewpath5.appspot.com/javascript/client-app-bundle.js --verbose

... we get the client-app-bundle.js as an uncompressed UTF8 resource along with a ETag HTTP response header whose value is a digest hash of the JavaScript file's data.

However, if I emulate my browser and set the Accept-Encoding HTTP request header to indicate to Google App Engine that my user agent (here curl) will accept a compressed resource, then I do not ever get the ETag HTTP response header.

```sh
$ curl --verbose https://xxxxxxxx.appspot.com/javascript/client-app-bundle.js
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying zzz.yyy.xxx.www...
* Connected to xxxxxxxx.appspot.com (zzz.yyy.xxx.www) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=*.appspot.com
*        start date: 2019-05-07 11:31:13 GMT
*        expire date: 2019-07-30 10:54:00 GMT
*        subjectAltName: xxxxxxxx.appspot.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=Google Internet Authority G3
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /javascript/client-app-bundle.js HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: xxxxxxxx.appspot.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 23 May 2019 00:24:06 GMT
< Content-Type: application/javascript
< Content-Length: 4153789
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< ETag: @encapsule/holism::kiA2cG3c9FzkpicHzr8ftQ
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
* Server @encapsule/holism v0.0.13 is not blacklisted
< Server: @encapsule/holism v0.0.13
< Via: 1.1 google
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
< 
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/        // The module cache
/******/        var installedModules = {};
/******/
.... and lots more JavaScript. Importantly note ETag in HTTP response headers.
```

COMPRESSED (FAILING) CASE:

```sh
$ curl --verbose -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" https://xxxxxxxx.appspot.com/javascript/client-app-bundle.js
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying zzz.yyy.xxx.www...
* Connected to xxxxxxxx.appspot.com (zzz.yyy.xxx.www) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=*.appspot.com
*        start date: 2019-05-07 11:31:13 GMT
*        expire date: 2019-07-30 10:54:00 GMT
*        subjectAltName: xxxxxxxx.appspot.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=Google Internet Authority G3
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /javascript/client-app-bundle.js HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: xxxxxxxx.appspot.com
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 23 May 2019 00:27:15 GMT
< Content-Type: application/javascript
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
* Server @encapsule/holism v0.0.13 is not blacklisted
< Server: @encapsule/holism v0.0.13
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Via: 1.1 google
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
�}{{G���˧�(�.rb�6`����1ƀw���,���4�$�23,���UU_碋-��
```

No ETag?

To me it seems incorrect that my application's custom ETag HTTP response header is removed; the gzip compression on the server and subsequent decompression in the user agent should be wholly encapsulated as an implementation detail of the network transport?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is caused by the NGINX proxy side car container that handles requests on GAE flex.

NGINX removes ETag headers when compressing content, maybe to comply with the strong identity semantics of the ETag, which is byte-by-byte, but not sure of that.

Unfortunately there is no way to configure the NGINX proxy in GAE Flex (other than manually SSHing into the container in each instance, changing nginx.comf, and restarting the nginx proxy).

The only workaround I know is to loosen the ETag strictness by making it "weak" by prepending "W/" to the value as specified in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232.

This is not documented. There's already an internal feature request to the App Engine documentation team to include this behavior in our public documentation.